# How to call a parameterized stored procedure using model in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, laravel-4

I made a store procedure in mysql named 'Insertusers' having 8 parameters in it.

Now i want to call this procedure using my model and insert value in table using this procedure.

Here is my Model's code :

```
<?php
    class Insertuser extends Eloquent {
        protected $guarded = array();

 public static function storedProcedureCall() {
         return DB::statement('Insertusers');
    } 
 public static $rules = array();
            }
?>
```

Here is my Controllers' code :

```
public function createUser() {
$clan = new Insertuser;
            $clan->clanname = Input::get('clanname');
            $clan->description = Input::get('tbx_new_clan_Des');
            if (Input::get('chk_new_clan_Status')) {
                $clan->active = true;
            } else {
                $clan->active = false;
            }
            if (Input::get('chk_new_clan_Incoming')) {
                $clan->allow_incoming = true;
            } else {
                $clan->allow_incoming = false;
            }
            if (Input::get('chk_new_clan_key')) {
                $clan->clan_key = Input::get('tbx_new_clan_key');
            }
            $clan->created_by = Session::get('userid');
            $clan->last_updated_by = Session::get('userid');
            $clan->DOMType=1;
            $clan->save();

}
```

When i tried to create a user, i am getting the following error :

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found.

Please help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: Is your table name "Insertusers"?

Comment: No, table name is users, InsertUsers is Procedure's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSSQL requires that variables within procedures be DECLAREd and folks use the @Variable syntax (DECLARE @TEXT VARCHAR(25) = 'text'). Also, MS allows for declares within any block in the procedure, unlike mySQL which requires all the DECLAREs at the top.

While good on the command line, I feel using the "set = @variable" within stored procedures in mySQL is risky. There is no scope and variables live across scope boundaries. This is similar to variables in JavaScript being declared without the "var" prefix, which are then the global namespace and create unexpected collisions and overwrites.

I am hoping that the good folks at mySQL will allow DECLARE @Variable at various block levels within a stored procedure. Notice the @ (at sign). The @ sign prefix helps to separate variable names from table column names - as they are often the same. Of course, one can always add an "v" or "l_" prefix, but the @ sign is a handy and succinct way to have the variable name match the column you might be extracting the data from without clobbering it.

MySQL is new to stored procedures and they have done a good job for their first version. It will be a pleaure to see where they take it form here and to watch the server side aspects of the language mature.

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution :

Here what i did in my controller :

```
 $clan_key;
            $clanname=Input::get('clanname');
            $description=Input::get('tbx_new_clan_Des');
            if (Input::get('chk_new_clan_Incoming')) {
                $allow_incoming = true;
            } else {
               $allow_incoming= false;
            }
             if (Input::get('chk_new_clan_key')) {
               $clan_key = Input::get('tbx_new_clan_key');
            }

            $created_by= Session::get('userid');
            $last_updated_by = Session::get('userid');
                    if (Input::get('chk_new_clan_Status')) {
                $active = true;
            } else {
                $active = false;
            }

            $DOMType=1;
            Clan::storedProcedureCall($clanname, $description, $allow_incoming, $clan_key,$created_by, $last_updated_by, $active, $DOMType);
```

Here is my Model :

```
class Clan extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'clans';

    public static function storedProcedureCall($clanname,$description,$allow_incoming,$clan_key,$created_by,$last_updated_by,$active,$DOMType) {
         return DB::select('call Insertusers(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',array($clanname,$description,$allow_incoming,$clan_key,$created_by,$last_updated_by,$active,$DOMType));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> No, table name is users, InsertUsers is Procedure's name.

Well in the code you have posted, you have not told Laravel that. Try this:

```
class Insertuser extends Eloquent {

   protected $table = 'users';
```

Comment: i am able to insert values in 'users' table using this syntax, but i want to insert values in 'users' table using 'Insertusers' procedure.

Comment: Well you need to check the Insertusers procedure - it probably has the table name there?

Comment: Yes, if i just call that procedure in mysql and pass values in that procedure, it is inserting the values in 'users' table.